# "to score coke off a student" meaning

Tags: phrases

I'm watching Grace & Frankie, a drama comedy. In the first episode when Frankie's adult children came over to console their mother over her husband (and thus their father's) recent coming out news, they tried to reassure that she would get through this. Coyote is a former alcoholic and drug addict, and a sub teacher.

Coyote (to her mom): Look at me (implying that he's had his ups and downs but now is sober and can hold down his job). What professor scores coke off her student?

The second son: and he (Coyote) wasn't even sleeping with his student.

I think coke refers to cocaine, but what does score coke off her student mean? Similarly, is "score something off someone" a phrase?

According to dictionary.com one meaning of score is to "Purchase or obtain drugs illicitly", and "Any success, happy acquisition." I looked up "off", and it has an informal meaning of "from". Putting two and two together, it seems clear that score off here means, obtaining a happy acquisition, here coke, from a student.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Questions are expected to show some research has been done. Please take the Tour and familiarise yourself with the site requirements https://english.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

score means 'get or buy' in this context. He would be a dubious professor, obviously.

It's a slang expression that originated from people buying or getting drugs. It's use has spread to where one has acquired or got (or won) something that is difficult to acquire or get.

Eg 'He scored a great date with that beautiful model!'

It's still slang, informal, street language.

According to this link, 'to score coke' can even simply mean, to have sex. Maybe someone from America can comment on that as I wasn't aware of it!

https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=score%20coke%20with

Comment: Thanks, Jelila! Would you say that in the same manner the phrase can be used in the following sentence: "I scored two milk cartoons off the supermarket on my way home last night?"

Comment: No, because it's a street slang expression that is quite... edgy. So it doesn't really work with household shopping. It also has a sense of winning - note it is the word 'score' like 'scored a goal'. It means, 'to luckily acquire something that is hard to come by'. So, I'd use it sparingly and only in suitable settings. Eg: 'wow! That undergrad scored a date with Tallulah - the top model! He scored a date with her? I don't get it!' Or 'wow! I was really lucky to score the best seat at the concert. Remember this expression does originate from people buying drugs - it's not ideal for your resume

Comment: Thank you kindly, Jelila! Really drove it home to me! Many thanks!

Comment: Great! @Basl glad it helped. Can you vote up my answer please? It's still unvoted for. Thanks! 

Comment: I tapped on the up arrow sign above once. Is that how you vote?

Comment: Yes @Basl thanks but maybe try again as the 0 should change into a 1. Unless someone else downvoted it. 

Comment: OK... Apparently, my vote does not go public, since I have less than "15 reputation," whatever that means! I tapped on it continuously but a message popped up telling me that. Sorry. But thanks for your very helpful explanation!